# Javascript: Why are my numbers not being raised to the nth power and being pushed to my array?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function that takes in a number and sums its range of digits to the nth power, but it seems like my function is not properly "n-thing" each number in the array.

Here's my code:

```
function sumDigPow(a, b) {
  var premArray = [];
  var squaredArray = [];
  for(var i = a; i <= b; i++){
    premArray.push(i);

  }
  for(var j = 0; j < premArray.length; j++){
      var squared = ('' + premArray[j]).split('').map(function(v, i){
        return Math.pow(parseInt(v), i + 1);
      }).reduce(function(a , v){
          return a + v;
      }, 0);

       squaredArray.push(squared);
    }
}

sumDigPow(5,22);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return the sum of the digits of n taken to the successive powers

```
function sumDigPow(a, b) {
  var squared = String(a).split('').map(function(v){
    return Math.pow(parseInt(v), b++);
  }).reduce(function(a , v){
      return a + v;
  });

  return squared;
}
```

sumDigPow(89, 1) => 89

sumDigPow(695, 2) => 1390

sumDigPow(46288, 3) => 2360688

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much over complicated entire thing.

```
function digPow(n, p){
  var total = 0;
  var digits = (""+n).split("");

  for (var i = 0; i< digits.length; i++) {
    total += Math.pow(digits[i], p+i);
  }

  if(total/n % 1 === 0){
    return total/n;
  }

  return -1;
}
```

Here we split first number to array. Mind that string times number can produce number if string is that of a number example: "6".

So we just split it, iterate through and calculate total result, after that we check if result divided with our start number (n) is int and we have simple solution. 
Hope it helps.